# How to disabled all unchecked checkboxes using each loop jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I've tried looking through various other solutions but none seem to work for me, so I'm posting this.

I have a booking calendar on a Wordpress site which allows users to select 1 hour long slots at a horse arena, and depending on their role (they have to be logged in to use it) the amount of hours is restricted. For example, three, four or eight hours. What I am trying to do is count up the number of checkboxes checked dynamically and then, when it reaches the allowed limit, it disables all other checkboxes UNTIL they decide to uncheck an existing checked one.

Here's my code:

```
$('.booking_font_cuprum').click(function(){
    var checked = $("input:checked").length;
    if( checked >= <?php echo $allowed_hours ?>) {
        $("input").each( function() {
            if($(this).not(':checked')) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("keep checking...");
    }
});
```

`$allowed_hours` is already stipulated in PHP above this, based on the user role (and it works). Basically what happens is that EVERY checkbox is disabled, and therefore the user cannot uncheck what they have already chosen. I thought that using the `:not` selector would only disabled unchecked, but maybe I'm implementing this incorrectly? I'd also need to re-enable all other checkboxes once one is unchecked, to allow the user to change their selection.

Comment: Could you add a small sample of your checkbox HTML to the question, so we can see exactly how this needs to work.

Comment: `$("input:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: @Satpal you are correct - my issue was that I was setting `disabled` as an attribute when it's a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).is(':checked')` and `$(this).not(':checked')`. And `disabled` is a property, so you should use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Below is small working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' checked />
<input type='checkbox' checked />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' checked />
<input type='checkbox' />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Emerson,

As per your coding standard, I have given the below working code.

I have tried the below code and is working fine.

```
$("input").each( function() {
   if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
});
```

One important thing that you have to remember, please go with a single approach. ie. Use either by setting 'attr' or 'prop'. Both will work fine.

But in case you are going to use both approaches for a same set of controls with various scenarios then you may have conflicts to set enable/disable value.